# Border color is missed on mobile view / lower resolution

Tags: html, css

I have problems with my radio buttons. On normal screen size (desktop pc) it looks all fine, but on mobile view (chrome developer tools) or at 90% and lower, the border color of the radio buttons disappears. To show it better, I have used a red border color. Could anyone explain me why this happens and how I can fix it?

```css
body{
  margin      : 0;
  padding     : 1.5em;
  font-family : Georgia,Utopia,Charter,serif;
}

.radiobutton{
  display: block;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old){
  width     : 2em;
  margin    : 0;
  padding   : 0;
  font-size : 1em;
  opacity   : 0;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label{
  display      : inline-block;
  margin-left  : -2em;
  line-height  : 1.5em;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old) + label > span{
  display          : inline-block;
  width            : 0.875em;
  height           : 0.875em;
  margin           : 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid red;
  border-radius    : 0.25em;
  background       : rgb(224,224,224);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
  vertical-align   : bottom;
}

input[type=radio   ]:not(old):checked + label > span{
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(224,224,224),rgb(240,240,240));
}

input[type=radio]:not(old):checked +  label > span > span{
  display          : block;
  width            : 0.5em;
  height           : 0.5em;
  margin           : 0.125em;
  border           : 0.0625em solid rgb(115,153,77);
  border-radius    : 0.125em;
  background       : rgb(153,204,102);
  background-image :    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :     -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :      -o-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image : -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
  background-image :         linear-gradient(rgb(179,217,140),rgb(153,204,102));
}
```

```html
 

<div class="radiobutton">
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked">  <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 1</label>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2"><label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 2</label>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" value="3"><label for="radio3"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 3</label>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="radiobutton">
      <input id="radio1" type="radio" name="radio" value="1" checked="checked">  <label for="radio1"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 1</label>
        <input id="radio2" type="radio" name="radio" value="2"><label for="radio2"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 2</label>
        <input id="radio3" type="radio" name="radio" value="3"><label for="radio3"><span><span></span></span>XXXX 3</label>
      </div>
enter code here
```

```css
input[type=radio ]:not(old) + label > span {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0.875em;
    height: 0.875em;
    margin: 0.25em 0.5em 0.25em 0.25em;
    border: 1px solid red;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    background: rgb(224,224,224);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgb(240,240,240),rgb(224,224,224));
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

the value which you have given for input border it is not taking. I have tried with other px values and it is working.

also check the box model which is there in the bottom right inspect element window, there your border value is not reflecting.

I have made the border width 1px

WORKING DEMO :[CLICK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/UIweb/q9fthupm/4/)